# Java: not-void methods as map values

Tags: java, dictionary, methods, interface, functional-programming

I have some code like this:

```
public class A {
    private final Map<String, Runnable> map = new HashMap<>();
    public A() {
        map.put("a", () -> a());
        map.put("b", () -> b());
    }
    public int a() {
        return 1;
    }
    public int b() {
        return 2;
    }
    public int c(String s) {
        // map.get(s).run(); <= returns void, but
        //                      I need the result of the 
        //                      function paired to the string.
        // What TODO?
    }
}
```

I have not-void functions (`a()`, `b()`) as values of a map, paired to Strings. I need to run the functions and get the result of the functions, and return it in the function `c()`. The `run()` function returns `void`, so I can't get the value from it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to return from `c`? 1? 2? Something else?

Comment: For example:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(c("a")); // Prints 1 - the result of calling a()
    }

Comment: why don't you use a custom interface instead of "Runnable"? But note that this "solution" to the problem you didn't expose is looking *bad* IMHO

Comment: If each value is a function which must return something, then you should use a Callable (or equivalent custom interface), not a Runnable

Comment: You may want to look at `Callable` instead of `Runnable`

Answer (score 6):

What you want to do here is to return an `int` value from the method. For that, you can't use a `Runnable` as `run()` doesn't return a value.

But you can use an [`IntSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html), which is a functional interface representing a function supplying an `int` value. Its functional method [`getAsInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html#getAsInt--) is used to return the value.

```
public class A {
    private final Map<String, IntSupplier> map = new HashMap<>();
    public A() {
        map.put("a", () -> a()); // or use the method-reference this::a
        map.put("b", () -> b()); // or use the method-reference this::b
    }
    public int a() {
        return 1;
    }
    public int b() {
        return 2;
    }
    public int c(String s) {
        return map.get(s).getAsInt();
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you don't want to return a primitive but an object `MyObject`, you can use the [`Supplier<MyObject>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) functional interface (or [`Callable<MyObject>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) if the method to call can throw a checked exception).

Comment: Thank you! But it seems I simplified my problem too much - is there any solution, where I can do this returning not an int but an own type from a class I created?

Comment: And if I have more types to return - can I use somehow something that would be like Supplier<T>?

Comment: @DisplayName Best you could do is `Supplier<Object>` if they share no type hierarchy (the least upper bound of the types).

Comment: @display what are the actual types being returned? Are they the same type as each other?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that lambdas are new does not mean they are necessary for every (perhaps any) solution.  Consider this tried-and-true java 5 feature (a little something called enumeration objects).

```
public class Enumery
{
    private static enum Stuffs
    {
        a(1),
        b(2);

        Stuffs(final int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int kapow()
        {
            return value;
        }

        final int value;
    }

    public int thing(final String stuffsName)
    {
        final int returnValue;
        final Stuffs theStuffs;

        theStuffs = Stuffs.valueOf(stuffsName);

        returnValue = theStuffs.kapow();

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```